# Preprocessor in C# is not working correctly

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

```
#if(DEBUG)
    ......Code......
#else
    ......Code......
#endif
```

I have some code like this. If my application is running in Debug mode it should execute the `#if(DEBUG)` part, if it is running in Release mode it should execute the `#else` part. However, it is only executing the `#if(DEBUG)` part no matter which mode it is running in.

Am using WPF application with VS2010

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say that your executing configuration is not precisely as expected. Where are you changing the configuration type? The standard toolbar, the solution properties configuration manager?

Comment: In the IDE, does it grey out the code in the DEBUG section when you choose release mode?

Comment: Yah it's greyed out for release mode

Answer (score 17):

For Debug Configuration, your project settings should look like

[image]

For Release they should look like this

[image]

Can you verify that this is the case, and let us know if it is?
If not, what is there for each configuration?

Comment: I have the same in my project settings also. but still it is not executing properly.

Comment: Search your code for `#define` statements, check are any of them defining `DEBUG`. If not, try defining your own debug constant `MYDEBUG` or something, don't put it in the project settings and see if your else branch executes.

Comment: If anyone has multiple env set up its defined under Conditional compilation symbols, for example if you want to use `#if UAT` then make sure build has UAT in the textbox.

Comment: For some reason this wasn't working for me, I checked `Define DEBUG constant` in Release and then unchecked it and it's fine now.

Comment: I uncheck the option of Define `DEBUG` constant when  the project it is in release mode. That's work for me, thank you!

Comment: @Ivan-San: Visual Studio - by default - gives you two different build configurations for Debug and Release, you shouldn't have to manually change flags to switch between.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new project using all the default settings and check that you can make that work as expected.  If so, your problem project must be "corrupted" in some way, perhaps by defining the DEBUG constant in the release configuration, or by having the debug project configuration selected for the release solution configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you putting DEBUG between parentheses?

```
#if DEBUG
    Code
#else
    Code
#endif
```

Comment: Using parens like this is legal, and not the issue here, however strange it looks. The issue might be the lack of a space after the `#if` directive.

Comment: @Oded - Nope, that is allowed also.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you create your configurations. For example if you create your configuration and use debug or release as a template DEBUG or RELEASE will be copied to the defined constraints element. It will not change the defined constraints element (in the project file) to the new configuration name.

Open up the project file and look for the configuration sections. Make sure the Platform, the below example it is "PROD" has an entry in the DefineConstants element. If it does the pre-compiler directives will don't work as expected in the code.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'PROD|x86'">
  <DefineConstants>PROD;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\PROD\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that in your project properties, under Build you have checked off `Define DEBUG constant`.

Try setting configuration mode to `Release` and run your application again. Default for `Release` is that the `DEBUG` constant is not defined, if you haven't tampered with if of course ;)

If `Define DEBUG constant` is *not* checked, that means you have a `#define DEBUG` lurking somewhere.

So two things to do. Check constant in options under Release mode, and check for any manually defined constant. It should be one of those.

Comment: His problem is that `DEBUG` IS executing, only all of the time.

Comment: Yes. It **is** executing because the DEBUG constant is defined in the project settings. I guess he believes it should not be executed unless be explicitly set #define DEBUG himself, but he will have to either run in Release mode, or uncheck this option for it to **not** run. Read my answer again...

Comment: The OP do not know that the constant must be defined. Else the topic would not be *Preprocessor in C# is not working*. Then it would be *Can't find out where DEBUG constant is defined*. Basically the only answer anyone can give is to assure him that the constant is defined somewhere so he can search for it, short of having him send me the code and search for the constant for him.

Comment: But I guess we will not agree to this, and that is fine. We are allowed to have different opinions.